# Multidimensional, associative array, foreach, return, recursion and bool

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my function:

```
function categoryExist($arr, $category):bool
{
    foreach ($arr as $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            //echo array_search($value, $arr);
            //echo "<br>";

            if (array_search($value, $arr) == $category) {
                //echo "yes!";
                return true;
            } else {
                categoryExist($value, $category);
            }
        } else {
            //echo $value . "<br>";
            if ($value == $category) {
                //echo "yes!";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the testing array:

$arr = [
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'D' => [
        'E',
        'F' => [
            'G',
            'H'
        ]
    ],
    'I' => [
        'J',
        'K'
    ],
    'L'
];

Here is the call:

```
if (categoryExist($arr, 'E')) {
    echo "I have it!";
}
```

How can I stop executing after first match using return and bool?

Comment: Can you show some sample input and your expected output?

Comment: I need true after first match, and false if there is no such category in the given array.

Comment: Does `D` exist in your sample array?

Comment: Yes, 'D' exists in the $arr.

Comment: So you want to check the keys as well as the values?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584726/php-doesnt-break-in-a-recursive-foreach-loop) might help

Comment: Yes Nick, I need to check whether 'E' exist as a key or a value inside.

Comment: jibsteros, yes, this is my case recursive function is called even when true appears below.

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to solve the problem. This function checks each key for a match, then checks the values, recursing if the value is an array. For each test, if the category is found `true` is immediately returned up the levels of the recursion. Only if no match is found is `false` returned. Note we use an `===` comparison with the key so that a `category` string such as `A` does not get treated as equal to a `key` of `0`.

```
function categoryExist($arr, $category) : bool
{
    $ce = false;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($category === $key) return true;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (categoryExist($value, $category)) return true;
        }
        else {
            if ($category === $value) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Sample testing code:

```
$arr = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' => [ 'E', 'F' => [ 'G', 'H' ] ], 'I' => [ 'J', 'K' ], 'L' ];
foreach (range('A', 'M') as $cat)
    echo "Category '$cat' " . (categoryExist($arr, $cat) ? '' : 'not ') . "found\n";
```

Output:

```
Category 'A' found
Category 'B' found
Category 'C' found
Category 'D' found
Category 'E' found
Category 'F' found
Category 'G' found
Category 'H' found
Category 'I' found
Category 'J' found
Category 'K' found
Category 'L' found
Category 'M' not found
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5I5f6)